# Facebook forcing Chinese characters in shares

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a site and a good portion of the URLs, but not all, are forcing to show Chinese characters in the URL description for Facebook shares (doesn't appear to happen with any other social media shares).

I've gone through everything I can find to help declare English as the site's language.

**HTML & Open Graph:**

```
<html lang="en" hreflang="en-us" >
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
```

**Facebook Script call includes English:**

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=161005447317900";
```

Though, when I use either the Share button built onto the page (part way down on the right) or paste the page's URL in Facebook it converts/interprets my characters into Chinese.

**Example Screenshot:**

[image]

Not sure it's worth noting, but I have attempted to change my charset from 8 to 16, but that didn't change anything.

[Here a page on the live site with the problem](https://www.sacnaturecenter.net/events/weekend-programs/).

Comment: What language you embed the JS SDK in has nothing to do with this. The Facebook scraper reads out the meta data, and what it sees when requesting your site you can see here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sacnaturecenter.net%2Fevents%2Fweekend-programs%2F I guess you have some kind of request language detection going on, and then serve different language versions under the same URL? That is not the way to do it; each language should have its own distinct URL.

Comment: Is there a way to detect or find out other language versions being served in that URL? I haven't created any different language versions under the same URL either... any clue where to check this?

Comment: No, if you did not implement anything like this, then that's probably not it. Not sure what is going on here, might be a DNS/routing issue. Try and ask your hosting company to look into it for you.

Comment: Will do - thanks for the tip. What's oddest about it is that it's only occurring on some pages too - others appear fine. I'll post if I finding anything on the server.

Comment: If it is a DNS or routing issue, it might be regional - Facebook has data center all over the world, so requests from different regions might be affected  or not. But then again since you are using HTTPS, it seems rather unlikely that Facebook would even accept a response from a different server - they are usually pretty strict about that, so if the request got mis-routed somewhere else, I would expect some error regarding SSL in debug tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the problem was being caused by a `<meta charset="UTF16">` declaration in the .

I had actually suspected that after finding some others commenting on this as a possibility in other Stackoverflow questions. However, I didn't catch it as Facebook's servers seem to keep cached responses/versions, so when you change it to utf-8, as an example, the link will still display the same results at times.

I decided to change it to utf-8 and let it sit for a couple of days and then come back and check - that did the trick.

Comment: I think CTRL+SHIFT+R should force a refresh of the cache or ignore cached content.